# Javascript change innerhtml of a tag

Tags: javascript

I am trying to change the text of the innerhtml depending on the current value. However, it isn't going in the if statements.

//HTML

```
<a class="btn" value="notadded" onclick="changetext(this.id,this.value)" id="wishlist">Add to wish list<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>
```

//Script

```
<script>function changetext(id,value) {
      if ( value == "notadded") {
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Added to Wishlist";
        document.getElementById(id).value = "added";
      } else if (value == "added")
      {
          document.getElementById(id).innerHTML= "Add to Wishlist";
          document.getElementById(id).value = "notadded";
      }
}
</script>
```

Comment: An anchor doesn't have a value, only form inputs do

Answer (score 2):

This issue here is that you cannot use value to get the text on that tag.

You're right there, only one small change:

Working Demo: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omarjmh/wu5qb00y/1/)

```
<a class="btn" value="notadded" onclick="changetext(this.id,this.value)" id="wishlist">Add to wish list<i class="fa fa-heart-o"></i></a>


<script>function changetext(id,value) {

        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Added to Wishlist";
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;

}
changetext("wishlist");
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Anchor tags do not have a value attribute

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a

However you could use a `data` attribute to do what you are doing.